# Email template div width is not changing with responsive media query

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a email template getting generated dynamically, I want to make it responsive.

I can't  make major change in structure.

here is my demo template link: http://jsbin.com/weyemida/1/watch

Please tell how to fix this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: is it you are asking for mobile phones and Tablets, then you can use @ media query syntax in css, rather than using inline css, like @media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 850px) { //Write you css properties here   }, the size 481px and 850px refers to width of the screen of devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use media queries. When your browser is smaller than a certain width, change some css.

Like this:

**CSS**

```
@media all and (max-width: 550px) // Change css when page's width is smaller than 550px
{
    .contentdiv {
        width: 100%; //change the container's width
    }

    table {
        width: 100%; // Make it the width of the container's size
    }
}
```

**JSBIN:** http://jsbin.com/bijixiga/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

try to just remove

```
    <style type='text/css'>
    @media only screen and (max-device-width:450px) {
        div[class=contentdiv] {
            width: 450px !important;
        }
    }
    .contentdiv{width:500px}
</style>
```